# How do I point Android Studio at my Java files?

Tags: android, android-studio

I mostly destroyed my android studio project by accident, and in trying to rebuild it, I've come to a point where the project won't run because it can't find my MainActivity - a java file - because the AndroidManifest.xml throws an error saying 'cannot resolve symbol MainActivity'. *edit: **I** know where this file is located, it's in the src directory, but **android studio** doesn't seem to know that, so can't start the MainActivity.*

Where is the path to these files set? ie, where does a module look for it's own java files? It doesn't seem to be in the Android facet section, that's only the paths to resources and assets, libraries and the manifest file, but that's the sort of thing I'm looking for.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking a question on the topic of "where did I put my source" ? :D

Comment: you put the java files in the src folder, not sure I understand the question though

Comment: *I* know where my files are, but *android studio* doesn't - I can't run the app because it can't find the MainActivity file.

Comment: Take a look at `<project name>.properties` in the project root.  Also check `Project Structure->Modules-><project>->Sources`

Comment: Did you try re-importing the project to Android Studio?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right-click on your `myproject` folder > `Mark as Directory` > `Source Root`

Comment: Thanks, it is a project, I think I'm just confused by the terminology. I suppose I assumed that it couldn't be the manifest file because the manifest file is where this line causes an error (cannot resolve symbol MainActivity): 'android:name="com.miguel.myproject.MainActivity'. Surely the manifest file doesn't look at itself in order to interpret a line like that?

Comment: @Miguel, you were right. I've lead you down the wrong path. I've just updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, that was spot on!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The cause for me was that I'd imported a source file from a different project and the package specifier at the top of the .java file was wrong:

```
package com.example.android.opengl;
```

Instead it should have referred to my current project.